# Ember.js: Route without template for calls to 3rd party APIs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm making a fairly simple app that has almost no state, so I'm a little bit confused about how best to use Ember routes.

The application consists of a list of objects ("commands") and a form. The user creates new objects by filling out the form. After they submit the form, the form is cleared out so they can take another action.

The attributes of commands are populated by calls to third party APIs, handled by a rails controller on the backend. Commands have a "type" attribute - depending on that type, we'll go to a different API and render a different template in the list.

It feels like I should use a route for each "new" call to a third party API, but in practice, since I don't want anything to change on the screen, this doesn't seem like the right approach. Really all I want is for the underlying collection of the list to change.

As a result, I basically have one very large controller to create all of the different types of commands, and instead of using a route I'm using jquery.getJSON.

I'm wondering if there's a more "Embery" way to structure this app - it feels like I'm fighting a little against the framework by using jquery.getJSON and having this gigantic controller smells a little bit to me.

Comment: Why not use a mixin for each command? Or just use a route with a dynamic segment. Here the segment will be the 'type attribute'. So you can use the same route for all the commands. You can put up ur api code at the route level.

Comment: @blessenm Thanks, mixin is definitely the best idea to combat my very large controller concern. I mocked up doing it with dynamic routes and I don't see it as being any better or worse than handling it all in the controller, so I'll probably leave that as is. I'm going to play around with the serializer and my adapter to see if I can use the store directly instead of jquery.getJSON.

Comment: if you are using plain jquery ajax. Use ic-ajax. It has better support with promises. https://github.com/instructure/ic-ajax